# Is there a way to make Omniture capture the url/page loaded via ajax as a "Load" event and not a "Click" event?

Tags: ajax, adobe-analytics

I am currently working on a Ajax based mobile website project and am not able to get Omniture to work correctly. Here is a brief detail of the problem.

- Assume a mobile site which has multiple pages, like example.com/a, example.com/b, example.com/c, example.com/d, example.com/e, example.com/f, etc.
- Each page of the site, has Omniture's code, like:

  ```
  <html><head></head><body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//domain-and-path-to-omniture-code-files/s_code.js">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  s.pageName = "blah";
  // some other ... s.blahBlah ... properties here...
  /************* DO NOT ALTER ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE ! **************/
  var s_code=s.t();if(s_code)document.write(s_code);
  </script>
  <div id="content">SOME CONTENT</div>
  </body>
  ```
- User opens the browser and opens one url/page, like example.com/a
- The page (example.com/a) has multiple links to the content on the same page, like #topic1, #topic2, #topic3, etc. and also has links to other static pages of the site, like example.com/b, example.com/c, example.com/d, etc.
- I use jQuery to control click events on these links.

  - When user clicks on a named link, like #topic1, #topic2, etc., the page is animated/smooth-scrolled to the target element/content-section; and Omniture's "s.tl()" function is triggered, to track/capture the click event with relevant/required details.
  - **## THIS IS THE PROBLEM AREA ##** When user clicks on a link to a different static page, like example.com/b, example.com/c, etc., instead of allowing the browser to do a full page-load, the Ajax version of the target page is loaded into the content holder *(by Ajax version, I mean to say that the page only has bare-minimum markup/content and not the entire html/head/common-css/js includes/etc)*.

Now the problem is that, when the page is loaded normally, Omniture captures it correctly as a "Load" event, but when it's loaded via JavaScript/Ajax, Omniture captures it as a "Click" event!

The Ajax/version of the page, does not include Omniture library "s_code.js" JS again (for obvious reasons, its already there on the parent/main page). Along with the required content, this page only has a script-tag, which sets required "s.blahBlah" values for the new page and the call to "s.t();".

I also tried to keep the Omniture code separate, in a common JS file, which is already loaded with the parent page, and only set the required "s.blahBlah" values in the Ajax call/function (which is also in a global/already loaded JS file), but still Omniture captures it as a "Click" event.

```
// s.tl(); ... gets captured as a click event
// s.t(); ... on normal page load... gets captured as a load event
// s.t(); ... after DOM-ready/page loaded via Ajax... gets captures as a click event
```

Any ideas! How can I make Omniture capture a load event? Is there a function like "s.l()" or something to trigger Omniture's "Load" event on demand.

Comment: `s.t` triggers a page view request, even if you pop it after page load.  You may have a plugin that's changing it (setting s.linkType), or you may have a plugin or other code that's triggering an additional `s.tl` call on top of your `s.t` call, or you maybe whatever you are using to look at the request being made is not showing it correct. If the request does not have a `pe=` param in it, then it's a page view request.

Comment: Thanks for the "pe=" param tip @Crayon. I use Omnibug to see what events are getting triggered from the page and it was showing the results incorrectly (https://github.com/simpsora/omnibug/issues/4). I've updated the tool and the issue is now resolved.

Comment: I have noticed that sometimes omnibug incorrectly shows a `s.t` call as a "click" event (light brown) instead of a page view event (blue). Usually when there's been an update to FireFox and/or Firebug

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not Omniture capturing it incorrectly, it was the tool "Omnibug", which I use to see the requests.

Omnibug 0.5.448 logs all "s.t()" calls made before page load event as Omniture "Load" event and any "s.t()" call made afterwards is captured as "Click" event.

Apparently, I was not the only one facing this issue. Others had already reported this to the developer of Omnibug (https://github.com/simpsora/omnibug/issues/4) and a fix has been made by him/a new version Omnibug 0.5.500 has been released.

The new version of Omnibug 0.5.500 captures all "s.t()" calls as "Load" events correctly and all "s.tl()" calls as "Click" event.

Thanks!

Comment: ObservePoint has a nice debugger. I don't like to use firefox so I end either using that or the DigitalPulse debugger.